# JavaScript Rendering

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't this HTML/script (from "Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja") render?

http://jsfiddle.net/BCL54/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function outer(){

  var a = 1;

  function inner(){ /* does nothing */ }

  var b = 2;

  if (a == 1) {
    var c = 3;
  }

}

outer();

assert(true,"some descriptive text");
assert(typeof outer==='function',
      "outer() is in scope");
assert(typeof inner==='function',
      "inner() is in scope");
assert(typeof a==='number',
      "a is in scope");
assert(typeof b==='number',
      "b is in scope");
assert(typeof c==='number',
      "c is in scope");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you didn't import the necessary script containing the assert function.

Comment: What do you expect to render? I see an empty `<body>` element.

Comment: The source of http://fiddle.jshell.net/BCL54/show/ is invalid, you cannot put a whole HTML document in there

Comment: Next time, hit CTRL+SHIFT+J in Chrome and you will find a good hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you didn't import Resig's necessary script containing the `assert` function :

```
<script>
function assert(pass, msg){
  var type = pass ? "PASS" : "FAIL";
  jQuery("#results").append("<li class='" + type + "'><b>" + type + "</b> " + msg + "</li>");
}
function error(msg){
  jQuery("#results").append("<li class='ERROR'><b>ERROR</b> " + msg + "</li>");
}
function log(){
  var msg = "";
  for ( var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++ ) {
    msg += " " + arguments[i];
  }
  jQuery("#results").append("<li class='LOG'><b>LOG</b> " + msg + "</li>");
}
</script>
```

You can find those functions in the source of [his site](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/). Note that those function also ask for jQuery and some DOM elements into which to write. You'd better adapt to your page.

Until you're proficient enough in javascript to rewrite those functions, you'd better do the excellent exercises directly on the site.

Comment: Also to add, he'll want a `ul` with id `results` in the body.